# Using Cauchy's Theorem and Contours To Compute an Integral

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I would like to receive some help on evaluating the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{z^n\,dz}{z^{2n}+1}$ because I am really new to integration over curves. So my thoughts were: The singularities of the fraction are at $z^{2n} = -1$ hence on the unit circle there are a certain number of evenly distributed singularity points (like roots of unity). I want to evaluate my integral and avoid these singularities. Assuming integer $n\geq2$

Consider the pie slice where we have a straight line from the origin to point R on the real line; then we travel up the arc of a circle of radius R centered at $0$ to the point $Re^{i\phi}$ I am not quite sure what to put for the angle, something that depends on $n$ say $\phi<\frac{\pi}{2n}$ will avoid the singularities from earlier; then we travel from this point to $0$ via a straight line.  The orientation for this closed curve is the positive orientation.

I am thinking that, by avoiding the singularities, I can say that the integral over this closed curve must be zero. After that I want to split the integral into the three parts, corresponding to the pieces of the closed curve. I have figured out so far that the integral along the arc of the circle of radius R centered at $0$ approaches $0$ as R approaches $\infty$ but I am stuck on what to do next in evaluating the remaining two integrals so I would appreciate as much guidance as possible, I really want to learn this type of integration well for a complex analysis class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason to use the suggested contour is not to *avoid the singularities* (these help, actually) but to have the constituent integrals *related* to the *given* integral (or evaluated some other way).

In our case, a good choice is $\color{blue}{\phi=\pi/n}$: $$\int_0^\infty\frac{z^n\,dz}{z^{2n}+1}=I\implies\int\limits_{\substack{z=re^{i\pi/n}\\0<r<\infty}}\frac{z^n\,dz}{z^{2n}+1}=-e^{i\pi/n}I,$$ so that, applying the residue theorem (and taking $R\to\infty$), you get $$(1+e^{i\pi/n})I=2\pi i\operatorname*{Res}_{z=e^{i\pi/2n}}\frac{z^n}{z^{2n}+1}=\frac\pi{n}e^{i\pi/2n}\implies I=\frac\pi{2n}\sec\frac\pi{2n}.$$

Comment: So @metamorphy you used the Residue theorem, unfortunately that’s a whole chapter ahead of where I’m at right now, do you know of a way to evaluate this only using Cauchys theorem and explicit evaluation?

Comment: Hey @metamorphy instead of using the residue theorem, could I use Cauchys integral formula to pick up a singularity like you did?

Comment: @Personal: Well, yes. Write $\frac{z^n}{z^{2n}+1}=\frac{f(z)}{z-e^{i\pi/2n}}$; then $f(z)$ has a *removable* singularity at $z=e^{i\pi/2n}$ (and the limit - that is, $f(e^{i\pi/2n})$ - is computed just like the residue above). And then you're at the preset (to apply Cauchy's integral formula).

Comment: interesting, I appreciate the discussion here so thank you for helping.